# Combining two LINQ expression projections

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, delegates

I have entity class:

```
public class Company
{
public int Id {get;set;}

public string Name {get;set;}

public int PrivateNumber {get;set;}

public DateTime Created {get;set;}

public DateTime? LastModified {get;set;}
}
```

I have DTO class:

```
public class CompanyDTO
{
public int Id {get;set;}

public string Name {get;set;}

public int PrivateNumber {get;set;}
}
```

For regular users, I'm using projection:

```
Expression<Func<Company, CompanyDTO>> proj1 = x => new CompanyDTO {
Id = x.Id,
Name = x.Name
};
```

For advanced users, I want to get private number as well so I define second projection

```
Expression<Func<Company, CompanyDTO>> proj2 = x => new CompanyDTO {
PrivateNumber = x.PrivateNumber
};
```

In first scenario, I write something like this:

```
CompanyDTO dto = ctx.Companies.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(proj1).FirstOrDefault();
```

For second scenario, I'd like to extend my proj1 with what is defined in proj2, so that I can improve query above to:

```
CompanyDTO dto = ctx.Companies.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(proj).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where proj is:

- Scenario 1 : proj = proj1
- Scenario 2 : proj = proj1 extended with proj2

Is this doable, and if yes, how?

Comment: Can you do it? Yes. Its pretty easy, since all you need to do it combine the `BindExpressions` on your `NewExpressions`. The OTHER question is, should you do it? My answer to that is, THE GOOGLES THEY DO NOTHING! Could I ask what you are trying to achieve so I might possible save your colleagues from this weirdness?

Comment: Perhaps you can try using `AutoMapper` and then create a `CompanyWithPhoneNumberDto : CompanyDto`. That would be SOOO much better. Then let `AutoMapper` deal with all the `ExpressionTree` stuff.

Comment: In scenario 1 I want to project 2 out of 5 properties to my DTO. In scenario 2 I want to project 3 out of 5 properties to my DTO. Clearly two properties in both scenarios are the same. Why would I write two select statements with 2/3 of projection detail being the same? Sorry but I'm not looking for outside solution, I'm asking if this can be done with regular C# Expressions.

Comment: Firstly. Automapper will allow you to do this by writing ZERO select expressions. You could implement this by telling Automapper that one expression you want to ignore one of the properties. Secondly, by simply not mapping your `PrivateNumber` prop, you lose information. If we were to re-persist your Dto back to the database, you couldn't tell if your user was trying to delete their phone number, or never had it in the first place. Sure, you could do a `if(user.IsAdmin())`, but then you end up with MORE code, not less.

Comment: Thank you for your theoretical support and suggestions about Automapper, but my question was rather clear. I'm asking for solution of the problem, not suggestions. If you can provide me the code that would merge two expressions into single expression, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I can't in good conscience do so. All I will tell you is that you need to use `ExpressionVisitor` to merge the `BindExpressions` within each `ConstructorExpression`, AND intern the two `ParameterExpressions` into one.